# How do I pass an ID using a button in React?

Tags: reactjs

This is my component. I'm trying to make a delete button that sends a `DELETE`  request to the server. What I'm struggling with is, **how do I pass the ID of the post to `handleDelete()`**?

```
import React from 'react';
import client from '../../api/';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap'
class Post extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.id = props.id
  }

  handleDelete(event) {
    console.log(event);
    alert(event.id);
    event.preventDefault()
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Title: {this.props.title} {this.props.id}</h1>
          <p>{this.props.body}</p>
          <Button id={this.props.id} onClick={this.handleDelete} color="danger">Delete</Button>
        </div>
      )}
}

export default Post
```

Comment: Use `this.props.id` inside the method `handleDelete`? No need to pass anything. Also  `this.id = props.id` is redundant, because you are duplicating the data sources.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but it says: TypeError: this.props is undefined

Comment: Ok that is due to the `binding`. Do `this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this)` inside the `constructor` function.

Comment: Check this code https://codesandbox.io/s/312y58k14p

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this)
}

handleDelete(event) {
  console.log(event)
  alert(this.props.id)
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.props.id and rewrite handleDelete function with arrow function to save components context

```
handleDelete=(event) => {
    console.log(event);
    alert(this.props.id);//here is post id
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: Note:  To use this syntax you need [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function to the onClick handler

```
<Button id={this.props.id} onClick={() => this.handleDelete(this.props.id)} color="danger">Delete</Button>
```

Comment: No need to pass. The component can use `props`.